# MAX GPU memory allocated during training for different torch version

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, gpu

I wrote the code below to test the GPU memory  for a training process. Here is the code

```
import os
import torch
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0"
to_mb = 1024**2
last_memory = 0

def get_gpu_memory():
    return torch.cuda.memory_allocated()/to_mb

def get_gpu_memory_change():
    global last_memory
    now_gpu = get_gpu_memory()
    changed = now_gpu - last_memory
    last_memory = now_gpu
    print(f"memory_usage_add:{changed} MB,  total_memory_usage_now:{now_gpu} MB")

def get_max_gpu_allocated():
    return torch.cuda.max_memory_allocated()/to_mb

data_type = torch.float32


class Model(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.linear = torch.nn.Sequential(torch.nn.Linear(10240, 10240,dtype=data_type),
                                          torch.nn.Linear(10240, 10240, dtype=data_type),
                                          torch.nn.Linear(10240, 10240, dtype=data_type),
                                          torch.nn.Linear(10240, 10240, dtype=data_type)
                                          )

    def forward(self,input):
        input = self.linear(input)
        # for index in range(100):
        #     input = self.linear[index](input)
        return input

# with torch.no_grad():
model = Model().cuda()
get_gpu_memory_change()
optimizer = torch.optim.AdamW(model.parameters())
get_gpu_memory_change()
data = torch.randn(1024, 10240, dtype=data_type).cuda()
get_gpu_memory_change()
batch_size = 1
print("*"*5+"now start Training"+"*"*5)
for each in range(batch_size):
    #print("*"*10)
    output = model(data)
    get_gpu_memory_change()
    print(f"after forward propagation, max gpu allocated is {get_max_gpu_allocated()} MB")
    loss = torch.sum(output)
    get_gpu_memory_change()
    loss.backward()
    get_gpu_memory_change()
    print(f"after backward propagation, max gpu allocated is {get_max_gpu_allocated()} MB")
    optimizer.step()
    get_gpu_memory_change()
    print(f"after optimizer step, max gpu allocated is {get_max_gpu_allocated()} MB")
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    get_gpu_memory_change()
print(torch.cuda.max_memory_reserved()/to_mb)
```

I run the code on NVIDIA  A100  with cuda version 11.7 on linux. And I got different result with torch 2.0.0 and torch 2.1.0.

For torch 2.0.0, results are

```
memory_usage_add:1600.15625 MB,  total_memory_usage_now:1600.15625 MB
memory_usage_add:0.0 MB,  total_memory_usage_now:1600.15625 MB
memory_usage_add:40.0 MB,  total_memory_usage_now:1640.15625 MB
*****now start Training*****
memory_usage_add:168.125 MB,  total_memory_usage_now:1808.28125 MB
after forward propagation, max gpu allocated is 1809.28125 MB
memory_usage_add:0.00048828125 MB,  total_memory_usage_now:1808.28173828125 MB
memory_usage_add:1488.28125 MB,  total_memory_usage_now:3296.56298828125 MB
after backward propagation, max gpu allocated is 3416.56396484375 MB
memory_usage_add:3200.3125 MB,  total_memory_usage_now:6496.87548828125 MB
after optimizer step, max gpu allocated is 9697.18798828125 MB
memory_usage_add:-1600.15625 MB,  total_memory_usage_now:4896.71923828125 MB
9982.0
```

and the max GPU memory allocated is 9697.18798828125 MB

For torch 2.1.0, results are

```
memory_usage_add:1600.15625 MB,  total_memory_usage_now:1600.15625 MB
memory_usage_add:0.0 MB,  total_memory_usage_now:1600.15625 MB
memory_usage_add:40.0 MB,  total_memory_usage_now:1640.15625 MB
*****now start Training*****
memory_usage_add:168.125 MB,  total_memory_usage_now:1808.28125 MB
after forward propagation, max gpu allocated is 1809.28125 MB
memory_usage_add:0.00048828125 MB,  total_memory_usage_now:1808.28173828125 MB
memory_usage_add:1488.28125 MB,  total_memory_usage_now:3296.56298828125 MB
after backward propagation, max gpu allocated is 3416.56396484375 MB
memory_usage_add:3200.3125 MB,  total_memory_usage_now:6496.87548828125 MB
after optimizer step, max gpu allocated is 8097.03173828125 MB
memory_usage_add:-1600.15625 MB,  total_memory_usage_now:4896.71923828125 MB
8382.0
```

and the max GPU memory allocated is  8097.03173828125 MB

Here is my analyze about max GPU memory allocated:
So just ignored the middle result during forward process and just considering model paraterms, gradient and optimizer state.
According to the adam document
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.optim.Adam.html#adam

I think for each parameter, we will have 4 optimizer state parameter related to it. So the peak of GPU memory usage is around 6 times for model parameter (1600MB) memory usage which should be around 9600 MB as the torch 2.0.0's result.

But with torch 2.1.0, the result is just about 1600MB less than torch 2.0.0's result, which just equal the memory usage of the model parameter.

Can anybody tell me what is the difference? Thanks

Comment: Presumably, the code got smarter and did better optimization.  Are you getting the right results?